# Magerun - Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket error message in console

Tags: php, database, error, magento-1, cli

By running this command on my localhost:

```
./n98-magerun.phar sys:cron:list
```

or

```
./n98-magerun.phar sys:check
```

I am getting this error messages:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20131226/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20131226/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: pdo_parse_params in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20131226/pdo_mysqli.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20131226/pdo_mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

and

```
  [Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception]                                                                                  
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) 
  [PDOException]                                                                                               
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Do you how can I get rid of of these messages?

Comment: probably by fixing and cleaning your php config

Comment: Can you me an example or smth how can I do that ? thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed in the etc/local.xml the host from

```
localhost to 127.0.0.1
```

and it works